# Evaluating $\sum_{\gcd\left(m,n\right)=1}\frac{1}{m^2n^2}$

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, reference-request, analytic-number-theory, riemann-zeta

I was wondering how one would evaluate the sum $$\sum_{\gcd\left(m,n\right)=1}\frac{1}{m^2n^2}.$$

The first thought that came to mind to to try something like this: $$\sum_{\gcd\left(m,n\right)=1}\frac{1}{m^2n^2}=2\sum_{\substack{\gcd\left(m,n\right)=1,\\m<n}}\frac{1}{m^2n^2}=2\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{f\left(k\right)}{k^2},$$

where $f\left(k\right)$ counts the number of ways that $k=mn$ for $m<n$ relatively prime. However, I can't see how I would proceed. Is this even the right way to be thinking about this?

In general, what techniques should I look into when looking at problems like this, and which books should I read to learn about these and similar techniques? Also, if this function $f$ has been studied before (and if it has a more standard notation/name), what should I search for to learn more?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

We have $$\sum_{d\ge 1} \sum_{\gcd(m,n)=d} \frac{1}{m^2 n^2}
= \zeta(2)^2$$
because we may classify all pairs $(m,n)$ according to their GCD.

On the other hand, this is also
$$\sum_{d\ge 1} \frac{1}{d^4} \sum_{\gcd(m,n)=1} \frac{1}{m^2 n^2}.$$
because when we divide the pair by their GCD we get a pair with GCD one.

Hence $$\sum_{\gcd(m,n)=1} \frac{1}{m^2 n^2} = \frac{\zeta(2)^2}{\zeta(4)}
= \frac{5}{2}.$$

**Addendum.** Trying to answer this question quickly yesterday I missed one of its salient features. Suppose $q(n)$ gives the number of ordered factorizations of $n$ into two factors that are co-prime to each other. This means if $p^v$ is a (maximal) prime power in the prime factorization of $n$ it has to go into one of the two factors at the full multiplicity (exponent $v$). Therefore we have
$$q(n) = 2^{\omega(n)}$$
where $\omega(n)$ is the number of distinct primes dividing $n$ (not counted according to multiplicity), because there are two possibilities for $p^v$ (first factor and second factor).

It was shown recently at this [MSE link](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1201200) that $$\Lambda(s) = \sum_{n\ge 1} \frac{2^{\omega(n)}}{n^s}
=\frac{\zeta(s)^2}{\zeta(2s)}.$$

The result then follows by setting $s=2.$

Comment: Thank you for your help. What sort of reference would you recommend that I look into to learn more about this and similar problems?

Comment: For starters you could use Wikipedia and maybe verify some of their identities on your own to check your understanding of the material. For example here they discuss [multiplicative functions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_function), which could prove useful e.g. to learn about the Dirichlet series for the Moebius function. Once you have mastered a significant part of their material and consulted some of their references you can then move on to work with any one of the major number theory texts of which I'm sure Eric can recommend quite a few.

Comment: Thanks! I haven't had any formal class in number theory beyond an elementary number theory course using Burton's text, so I believe I'll have a lot to learn.

Comment: I have added some material just now that I believe could be useful to initiate further study.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! This is very interesting, and I'm glad that my idea was at least a correct (though maybe not quite as direct) approach to this problem.

Answer (score 13):

Using the fact that $$\sum_{d|n}\mu(d)=\begin{cases}
1 & \text{if }n=1\\
0 & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$$ where $\mu(d)$ is the [mobius function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M%C3%B6bius_function), we can write $$\sum_{\gcd(m,n)=1}\frac{1}{m^{2}n^{2}}=\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{m^{2}}\frac{1}{n^{2}}\sum_{d|m,d|n}\mu(d).$$ Switching the order of summation so that we sum over $d$ first, this becomes $$\sum_{d=1}^{\infty}\mu(d) \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(dm)^{2}}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(dn)^{2}},$$ and this may be split up to find that your sum equals $$\sum_{d=1}^\infty \frac{\mu(d)}{d^4}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{m^2}\sum_{m=1}^\infty \frac{1}{n^2}=\frac{\zeta(2)^2}{\zeta(4)}=\frac{5}{2}.$$

Comment: Thank you, this is much simpler when it's right there in front of you. What references would you recommend to learn more?